# How to have all '<li>' with the same height when mapping over an array?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am mapping over an array of 'services' and transforming each one in a `<li>`. Their names vary, some very short, others longer that take up two lines.

The photo may look like a table but I really intend to do this with `<li>`.

I would like to have all of the `<li>` of the same height as those that take up the most space. I've tried `min-height` but that won't fit nicely like they should (filling all of the empty space)

[image: lis]

This is what I'm trying

```
serviceList.map(service => <li className="service">service</li>)
```

```
.service {
       border-radius: 0; 
    // min-height: 10px; //doesn't fill the empty spaces nicely
       width: 20%;
       padding: 12px
}
```

Comment: Inside of one line, you could have that relatively easy, if you make the UL `flex`. If you want this across all lines, same height for _all_ items - then you will probably have to use JavaScript to determine the maximum height, and then set that explicitly.

Comment: flex will do for  each li of the same row the same height, grid can do every row and lis the same height...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the parent as `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap`. It'll make sure that all of the children to correspond with the same height.

I've created a simple demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-silence-ojfzz?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.gridcell2 .module:nth-of-type(1n+2)').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.gridcell2 .module:nth-of-type(1n+2)').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Infos: here is the `grid` option setting each `li` to the height of the tallest one:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
}
 


/* optionnal extra makeup ? */


ul {
  background: #164fb7;
  padding: 1em;
}

li {
  border: solid;
  padding: 0.15em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2px;
  background: #bee
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>longer longer </li>
  <li>2<br>lines</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum color </li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>longer longer </li>
  <li>2<br>lines</li>
  <li>might <br>be the <br> tallest </li>
  <li>short</li>
  <li>unless this is that one the tallest on smaller screen </li>
  <li>1 line</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum color </li>
</ul>
```